# How can i reload UIPickerView with no scrolling to first ellement? (obj c)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to reload UIPickerView components, but it scroll to first row.

The problem: it need to remain selected on current row (i need only update 
 rows). 
At moment using `[stringPicker reloadAllComponents];`

Can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Get the currently selected row, reload the components, then select the previously selected row (without animation).

```
NSInteger currentRow = [stringPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]; // or whatever component
[stringPicker reloadAllComponents];
[stringPicker selectRow:currentRow inComponent:0 animated:NO];
```

If the reloaded component might have less rows than it did before being reloaded, you need to ensure that `currentRow` isn't too big for the reloaded component.

Comment: I have similar code, but it work "randomly", i dont know why. i check and debug currentRow -> is ok. Sometimes it scroll to first, sometimes work ok. Also trying with dispatch - nothing

Comment: Then update your question with your actual, relevant code.